# C++ builder binding data at runtime

Tags: abstract-class, firemonkey, c++builder, livebindings

Trying to bind `TClientDataSet` to `TStringGrid` at runtime on [Delphi modele](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411339/) below:

```pascal
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    Grid1: TGrid;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;
[...]

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AField : TField;
  BindSourceDB1 : TBindSourceDB;
  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1 : TLinkGridToDataSource;
  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB2 : TLinkGridToDataSource;
begin
  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'ID';
  AField.FieldKind := fkData;
  AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

  AField := TStringField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'Name';
  AField.Size := 20;
  AField.FieldKind := fkData;
  AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

  BindSourceDB1 := TBindSourceDB.Create(Self);
  BindSourceDB1.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1 := TLinkGridToDataSource.Create(Self);
  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1.DataSource := BindSourceDB1;
  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1.GridControl := Grid1;

  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB2 := TLinkGridToDataSource.Create(Self);
  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB2.DataSource := BindSourceDB1;
  LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB2.GridControl := StringGrid1;

  ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1, 'AName']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([2, 'AnotherName']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([3, 'ThirdName']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([4, 'FourthName']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([5, 'FifthName']);
  ClientDataSet1.First;

end;
```

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to instantiate the `LinkGridToDataSource` object. I received following error message:

> Allocating an object of abstract class type 'Data::Bind::Grid::TLinkGridToDataSource'.

Here is my code:

```cpp
  ...
  BindSourceDB1 = new TBindSourceDB(this);
  BindingsList1 = new TBindingsList(this);
  LinkGridToDataSource1 = new TLinkGridToDataSource(this);
  ...
```

Any help?

Comment: The compiler should be telling you *why* the class is abstract (ie, what method(s) are not implemented). But if the code works in Delphi, it *should* also work in C++, unless you have encountered a codegen bug that needs to be escalated to Embarcadero.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, many thanks! Two methods was reported : Data.Bind.Components.hpp(3059): Unimplemented pure virtual method 'Reactivate' in 'TLinkGridToDataSource' & Data.Bind.Components.hpp(3065): Unimplemented pure virtual method 'RequiresControlHandler' in 'TLinkGridToDataSource'.
As regard bugs the following is already fixed in fixed in 10.4 Sydney which is my current version :"TLinkGridToDataSource.AutoActivate works only at design time". Not sure it is related to my issue. Cf. :https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/List_of_publicly_reported_bugs_fixed_in_10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the code below worked :

in unit.h

```
...
#include <REST.Client.hpp>  // For TRESTClient, TRESTRequest & TRESTResponse
#include <REST.Response.Adapter.hpp>  // For TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter
#include <Datasnap.DBClient.hpp>   // For TClientDataSet
#include <Data.Bind.DBScope.hpp>   // For TBindSourceDB
#include <Data.Bind.Grid.hpp>  // For TLinkGridToDataSource
...
class oTLinkGridToDataSource : public TLinkGridToDataSource
{protected:
  virtual void __fastcall Reactivate() override;
  virtual bool __fastcall RequiresControlHandler() override;

 public:
   __fastcall virtual oTLinkGridToDataSource(System::Classes::TComponent* AOwner){}
   __fastcall virtual ~oTLinkGridToDataSource(){}
};
...
```

in unit.cpp

```
void __fastcall oTLinkGridToDataSource::Reactivate()
{//
}
//-----
bool __fastcall oTLinkGridToDataSource::RequiresControlHandler()
{return true;
}
//-----
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
 TRESTClient *RESTClient1 = new TRESTClient(this);
 TRESTRequest *RESTRequest1 = new TRESTRequest(this);
 TRESTResponse *RESTResponse1 = new TRESTResponse(this);
 TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter *RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1 = new TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter(this);
 TClientDataSet *ClientDataSet1 = new TClientDataSet(this);

 RESTClient1->BaseURL = "myURL.com";
 RESTRequest1->Client = RESTClient1;
 RESTRequest1->Response = RESTResponse1;

 RESTResponse1->ContentType = "application/json";
 RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1->Dataset = ClientDataSet1;
 RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1->Response = RESTResponse1;
 RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1->Active = true;
 RESTRequest1->Execute();

TBindSourceDB *BindSourceDB1 = new TBindSourceDB(this);
oTLinkGridToDataSource *LinkGridToDataSource1 = new oTLinkGridToDataSource(this);
 //--
 BindSourceDB1->DataSet = ClientDataSet1;
 LinkGridToDataSource1->BindingsList = BindingsList1;
 LinkGridToDataSource1->DataSource = BindSourceDB1;
 LinkGridToDataSource1->GridControl = StringGrid1;

}
//-----
```

Hope this will help.